# Should we make tapGesture component an IBAction or IBOutlet to capture the tap event?

Tags: ios, swift

When I want a tap response on my main View in my ViewController

A. I could create an `IBOutlet` as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped))
  }

  @objc private func tapped(_: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Log is here")
  }
}
```

Or

B. I could an `IBAction` on the TapGesture such as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func tapGestureAction(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Log is here")
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Is there a preferred approach of one above the other? If not, which situation should we use A approach, and which we should use B approach?

Comment: i guess this question is someHow silly and should be downvoted creating it in IB or code will make no difference it's an opinion based and should be closed too

Comment: I disagree @Sh_Khan, the fact that there is more than one approach means there's something to learn here, even if both approaches are functionally the same.

Comment: Both approaches work, but if you’re going to create gesture in IB, why not just hook up the action method there, too? Option A introduces unnecessary code and is simply a possible source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Option B, i.e. just having the `@IBAction` outlet would be preferred when you already created your `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the storyboard, as this encapsulates as much logic as possible in the storyboard, reducing the overhead of reading unnecessary code and potential regressions if/when the code is refactored (but the storyboard remains unchanged).

You can still mark the `@IBAction` private (as it's effectively the same as using an `@objc` attribute). Also, if you need to access the gesture recognizer itself, you can have a regular `@IBOutlet` with a `didSet` to modify it, or change `sender: Any` to `sender: UITapGestureRecognizer` to access it in the action.

Answer (score 2):

It is an interesting question, from my perspective this depends on how much from your application is in the storyboard or you want it explicitly written in the code. 
My recommendation will be if you are doing something small and it should be done fast to use your storyboard. But if you have a big project with a big team then it will be better to have it in the code.

The other thing that can be a key factor for these approaches will be who is the owner of the reference and do you want to have some interactions of the gesture. For example, I have a gesture that should be enabled in specific cases and for others, it should be disabled. For this, you need to have a reference in the code.

What I'm trying to explain is that you should think for criteria like how and when you can use this gesture. And based on this to decide if you need less code or reference to the gesture or whatever you need

Comment: `But if you have a big project with a big team then it will be better to have it in the code.`, welp, now we need to close the question as being opinion based. I have worked on big teams and big projects, and the less UI setup code we have, the easier it is to maintain. Specially for things that rarely changes (such as UI setup code)

Comment: yep, you are right, it is mether of opinion. And more important it how the teams expects to work. Different teams can handle this in different ways. What I'm trying to explain is that you should think for criteria like how and when you can use this gesture. And based on this to decide if you need less code or reference to the gesture or whatever you need.

Comment: Storyboards are not the problem in big projects, but rather the failure to break the single, huge `Main.storyboard` into smaller, more manageable ones.

Comment: Storyboards are not a problem, totally agree with you. But for sure it is easier to understand if you have gesture in the code compear to search in the storyboard for it(again I need to say it is personal perspective). And for sure it is better if you have several storyboards, not one big.

Comment: And, FWIW, the question here wasn’t “should I create gestures in IB vs programmatically” but rather “I’ve already created tap gesture in IB, and am wondering whether I should also hook up the action method there, too”.